# Android deploy with fastlane image playstore order

Tags: fastlane

In android fastlane there is a directory

```
fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/phoneScreenshots
```

Inside that directory I see a number of images:

```
1_en-US.jpeg
2_en-US.jpeg
3_en-US.jpeg
```

When I go to the Google Playstore I see the images show up in order based on the numbering of the jpegs. I want to update those images manually as I got some new images. I want to confirm that the image order that appears in Google play is defined by the numbering of the image? ie, `1_en-Us.jpeg` will appear before `2_en-Us.jpeg` and so on?

A follow up question is if I now manually change the images and I want to do a new deploy is there anything else that needs to be in the deploy lane? Currently I just have:

```
desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    # gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'Release',
      properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "/somewhere",
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "something",
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "something",
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "something",
      }
    )
    upload_to_play_store
  end
```